# Backing up Tortoise SVN files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Hi 
Thank you for the responses

I'm new to this

I am trying to find out, where is the physical path of the SVN repository is on my Window Server so that I am able to back the files up.

Does someone know where they could be stored and the best way of backing them up.

Thank you

Comment: Where is your SVN repository located?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Tortoise (which is an SVN _client_), but all with the SVN _server_, which you haven't told us about. @lalit asked exactly the right question. I at least added the `svn` tag, so those who know about SVn, but not about Tortoise, will have a chance to see this.

Comment: @sbi: I would interpret the question as "How can one use Tortoise SVN to find out where the repository is?"

Comment: @Doc: Yeah, that might be it. And then it might not.

Answer (score 2):

Committed files are stored in a [SVN repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.repository.html). Typically repositories are managed (and backed up) by the IT guys somewhere on a server on your network. However, you can also create repositories on your local file system if you want.

To discover the location of your repository, right-click on a folder in your working copy and open the TortoiseSVN repository browser. At the top of the repository browser is a URL. The start of this URL is also repeated in the treeview on the left: this should point at the location of your repository. If it is a `file:` URL, then your repository is probably stored on your local filesystem somewhere. If it is a `svn:` or `http:` URL, then most likely the repository is on another server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows: run the repo browser and look at the URL on top of the window.